# How do you control the formatting of digits when converting lists of numbers to character?

Tags: r, formatting

I have a nested list containing numbers, for example

```
x <- list(1 + .Machine$double.eps, list(rnorm(2), list(rnorm(1))))
```

If I call `as.character` on this, all the numbers are given in fixed format, to 15 significant digits.

```
as.character(x)
## [1] "1"                                                                      
## [2] "list(c(0.654345721043012, 0.611306113713901), list(-0.278722330674071))"
```

I'd like to be able to control how the numbers are formatted.  At the very least, I'd like to be able to control how many significant figures are included.  As a bonus, being able to specify scientific formatting rather than fixed formatting would be nice.

The `?as.character` help page states:

> as.character represents real and complex numbers to 15 significant
>   digits (technically the compiler's setting of the ISO C constant
>   DBL_DIG, which will be 15 on machines supporting IEC60559 arithmetic
>   according to the C99 standard). This ensures that all the digits in
>   the result will be reliable (and not the result of representation
>   error), but does mean that conversion to character and back to numeric
>   may change the number. If you want to convert numbers to character
>   with the maximum possible precision, use format.

So it doesn't appear to be possible to change the formatting using `as.character` directly.

Calling `format` destroys the list structure:

```
format(x, digits = 5)
## [1] "1"                          "0.65435, 0.61131, -0.27872"
```

`formatC` throws an error about not supporting list inputs.

`deparse` also doesn't allow users to change how numbers are formatted: `as.character(x)` is the same as `vapply(x, deparse, character(1))`.

This is almost correct, but there are extra double-quote characters around the numbers that I don't want:

```
as.character(rapply(x, format, digits = 5, how = "list"))
## [1] "1"
## [2] "list(c(\"0.65435\", \"0.61131\"), list(\"-0.27872\"))"
```

How do I control the formatting of the numbers?

---

A partial solution: for reducing the number of significant figures, I can adapt the previous example by converting to character using format, then back to numeric.

```
as.character(rapply(x, function(x) as.numeric(format(x, digits = 5)), how = "list"))
## [1] "1"                                       "list(c(-1.0884, 1.6892), list(0.58783))"
```

This doesn't work if I want to increase the number of sig figs beyond 15 or use scientific formatting (since we run into the limitation of `as.character`).

```
as.character(rapply(x, function(x) as.numeric(format(x, digits = 22)), how = "list"))
## [1] "1"                                                                  
## [2] "list(c(-1.08842504028146, 1.68923191896784), list(0.5878275490431))"
```

Comment: You could traverse your tree of lists, applying `sprintf` or similar only on its 'leaves'.

Comment: That was pretty much my idea in that last `rapply` example.  If you can make it work better using `sprintf`, I'd love to see your solution.

Comment: This probably ought to be implemented in R itself, so I submitted a bug https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16866. Workarounds still appreciated, since getting changes into R at this low-level are nearly impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play with the `how` argument to `rapply()`:

```
> rapply(x, sprintf, fmt = "%0.5f", how = "replace")
[[1]]
[1] "1.00000"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "0.18041"  "-0.63925"

[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "0.14309"
```

For more digits, change `fmt`:

```
> rapply(x, sprintf, fmt = "%0.22f", how = "replace")
[[1]]
[1] "1.0000000000000002220446"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "1.2888001496908956244880" "1.0289289081633956612905"

[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "0.4656598705611921240610"
```

You can `gsub()` out the quotes:

```
> gsub("\"", "", deparse(rapply(x, function(z) sprintf(fmt = "%0.22f", z), how = "replace")))
[1] "list(1.0000000000000002220446, list(c(1.2888001496908956244880, "
[2] "1.0289289081633956612905), list(0.4656598705611921240610)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Advice given to me by R Core member Martin Maechler was that you can format the numbers in a `"%g17"` style (that is R decides whether fixed or scientific formatting is best, and increases the number of significant digits to 17; see `?sprintf`) by using deparse and the `"digits17"` controls option.  The latter is documented on the `?.deparseOpts` help page.

```
vapply(x, deparse, character(1), control = "digits17")
```